# SQL Query according to the situation shown in the body

Tags: sql

I have two tables named Cities and Banks

Cities have Columns named CityId and CityName

Banks have a Column BankCity.

BankCity have data same as in CityName, but i want to replace BankCity data with CityId.

But I cant find a query for it.

Comment: 1) ALTER TABLE to add new column.

Comment: 2) UPDATE that new column.

Comment: 3) ALTER TABLE, drop old column.